# Simulate mouse out event in nightwatch-cucumber

Tags: javascript, selenium, cucumber, nightwatch.js, e2e-testing

In my app I have an event fired when cursor leaves page area. Is it any way to simulate that in Nightwatch tests? I know I can't move the pointer by javascript, but maybe someone had the same problem. I know how to move to different elements in the DOM, but I don't have an idea how to simulate leaving the page.
Greetings

Comment: I would try with [moveToElement](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/moveToElement.html) to move over the area and to then move over an element outside the area.

Answer (score 1):

> .moveToElement('@selector',Xoffset,Yoffset)
>
> .mouseButtonClick(0)